# Shutdown warning every time I log on

Tags: macos, error, startup, shutdown

Whenever I log on, I get the "Your computer crashed previously, do you want to restart the running programs?" error; regardless of whether my machine crashed or not. Whether I press OK or Cancel, it comes back the next day.

While my machine crashes quite regularly, it usually shuts down cleanly. Presumably, therefore, this error is flagged via some stuck setting.

How do I "unstick" it?

---

**EDIT** The actual error message:

> **You shut down your computer because of a problem.**
>
> If you want to open the applications that were open when you shut
>   down, click Open.
>
> If you do nothing, the computer will continue the login in [countdown]
>   seconds.

I don't know what to look for in the logs, but I can isolate the time down to the nearest minute and this is what I get (hopefully this doesn't expose any compromising data!):

```
06/07/2015 10:00:54.477 am com.apple.launchd.peruser.15022[322]: Background: Aqua: Registering new GUI session.
06/07/2015 10:00:54.503 am com.apple.launchd.peruser.15022[322]: (com.apple.EscrowSecurityAlert) Unknown key: seatbelt-profiles
06/07/2015 10:00:54.504 am com.apple.launchd.peruser.15022[322]: (com.apple.ReportCrash) Falling back to default Mach exception handler. Could not find: com.apple.ReportCrash.Self
06/07/2015 10:00:54.514 am distnoted[327]: # distnote server agent  absolute time: 18.231856073   civil time: Mon Jul  6 10:00:54 2015   pid: 327 uid: 15022  root: no
06/07/2015 10:00:59.471 am com.apple.launchd.peruser.15022[322]: (com.adobe.ARM.202f4087f2bbde52e3ac2df389f53a4f123223c9cc56a8fd83a6f7ae[376]) Job failed to exec(3). Setting up event to tell us when to try again: 2: No such file or directory
06/07/2015 10:00:59.471 am com.apple.launchd.peruser.15022[322]: (com.adobe.ARM.202f4087f2bbde52e3ac2df389f53a4f123223c9cc56a8fd83a6f7ae[376]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 2
06/07/2015 10:00:59.472 am com.apple.launchd.peruser.15022[322]: (com.user.boot2docker[375]) Job failed to exec(3). Setting up event to tell us when to try again: 2: No such file or directory
06/07/2015 10:00:59.472 am com.apple.launchd.peruser.15022[322]: (com.user.boot2docker[375]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 2
06/07/2015 10:00:59.555 am WiFiKeychainProxy[347]: [NO client logger] <Nov 10 2013 18:30:13> WIFICLOUDSYNC WiFiCloudSyncEngineCreate: created...
06/07/2015 10:00:59.555 am WiFiKeychainProxy[347]: [NO client logger] <Nov 10 2013 18:30:13> WIFICLOUDSYNC WiFiCloudSyncEngineRegisterCallbacks: WiFiCloudSyncEngineCallbacks version - 0, bundle id - com.apple.wifi.WiFiKeychainProxy
06/07/2015 10:00:59.702 am ReportPanic[351]: ReportPanic could not stat /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Kernel_2015-06-22-170843_mib107490i.panic
06/07/2015 10:00:59.709 am com.apple.launchd.peruser.15022[322]: (com.apple.mrt.uiagent[355]) Exited with code: 255
06/07/2015 10:00:59.953 am Flux[389]: Invalid color System, labelColor (warning given only once)
```

My guess is it's the `ReportPanic` line, but that's just a hunch!

Comment: For starters, I would **Repair Disk** HD in Disk Utility. If the opton is grayed out, use Recovery HD or Internet Recovery. And perhaps reset PRAM ( **Command** + **Option** + **P** + **R** ) on boot and wait for the chime to play the 2nd time

Comment: Clearing PRAM is no cure for everything.

Comment: Repair Disk on Macintosh HD was disabled, but not on its parent device; it didn't achieve anything. Neither did resetting the PRAM. It's a managed machine -- I was just hoping for an easy fix -- so I'll see what my service people say.

Comment: What does the log say when you start the computer?

Comment: @TheBro21 I misread your comment. I have now updated the question with the log output during the time in which the error occurs.

Comment: Are you using any third party kernel extensions? Also try repairing permissions

Comment: I don't know about kernel extensions. Repairing permissions didn't make a difference.